# Define Module Dependencies in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

How can we ensure that the first module “frontend_1” is executed before the rest?

```
module "frontend_1" {
  source = "/modules/frontend-app"
}
module "frontend_2" {
  source = "/modules/frontend-app"
}
module "frontend_3" {
  source = "/modules/frontend-app"
}
```

Also - there're a couple of recorded Gitissues re this problem but a good workaround has not been presented in any of them. As a start - you can check this one so that you can get familiar with the essence of my question - https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/10462

And how to make an external for a module resource be built before the module gets executed - so that the "count" can be computed if it depends on a value which is calculated from such an external resource?
For example - if you need to use the ID of a newly created VPC in the "count" in a module which creates multiple AWS Security Groups within that VPC?

Comment: I hope my answer answers your question. But maybe you describe a bit more, what you actually want to achieve as your requirement feels a bit unusual.

Comment: It does not. And it's pretty needed actually - if you create a resource using a module and then create another resource using the same module but the second resource needs the ID of the first resource... it's not possible to get that and use it in the second resource.

Comment: I've deleted my answer about the obvious, yet not existing, `depends_on` for modules. Seems I oversimplified terraform once again ;-)

Comment: Passing an output of one module to a variable of another works, doesn't it? Or what code "needs the ID of the first resource"? A data resource?

Comment: For some reason it does not work in my case - I'm trying to pass the ID of an AWS Security Group which gets created by a module to another initialisation of the same module which creates a second SG which uses the ID of the first SG in its source ingress rules.

Comment: And yes - a "data" source of type "null_data_source". I've been trying to create a flexible module for creation of multiple AWS SG's.

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned in the question, I was able to make a workaround for you using the `depends on` variable.

Refer to [this](https://www.terraform.io/intro/getting-started/dependencies.html) for Terraform dependencies.

Assume we have 2 modules, one which defines the vpc and subnets, the second to define the various range of security groups to be used in the Infrastructure.

Since we have the dependency such that all security groups are to be made only after the successful creation of vpc in the VPC module, it can be met by the following strategy.

```
variable "vpc_arn" {
   description = "The ARN of the VPC which is created in the VPC module"
}

resource "null_resource" "vpc_found" {
  triggers = {
    vpc_name = "${var.vpc_arn}"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "allow_all" {

  depends_on = ["null_resource.vpc_found"]

  name        = "allow_all"
  description = "Allow all inbound traffic"
  vpc_id      = "${var.vpc_arn}"
  ......
}
```

Refer to [this](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/null_resource.html) for null resources.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the answer. It works as expected.

Answer (score 7):

Modules are not a bundle of resources that are all created or all destroyed as a single unit, so there is no sense in which one module is run before or after another. If you look at the output of [terraform graph](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/graph.html), you'll see that the individual resources within a module appear as nodes in the plan graph which the execution engine traverses concurrently. This means that it's entirely possible to have bidirectional dependence between two modules (module A takes inputs from module B output, and also provides outputs which are used for module B input), as long as the plan graph does not contain a cycle.

One thing to observe with Terraform is that the plan graph is constructed by looking at which resource attributes, variables, inputs outputs, etc depend on which other ones via interpolation, in combination with any explicitly declared dependencies using depends_on (which is not available for modules). The consequence of this for your above example is that if there are no interpolation references which link values from the output of one module to the input of another, then there can be no paths constructed in the plan graph which indicate any dependency between the resources.

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation, Sam!

Comment: This is a good answer but I don't think the last couple of paragraphs are true. In my experience and from quick testing now to confirm Terraform will wait for a resource to be created fully (including any provisioners attached to the resource) before starting to create another resource that depends on the first via either `depends_on` or interpolation.

Comment: Indeed the dependency graph is created from the static references, regardless of whether their values are "known" yet or not. Terraform will include that actual resource name in the plan output when it's able, but it'll still work on `some_resource.thing` before `some_other_resource.other_thing` even if that `name` attribute already has a known value.

Comment: @MartinAtkins And how to make an external for a module resource be built before the module gets executed?

Comment: Thanks for your correction. I've removed the misleading tip. I was sure I had this problem before that I was offering a tip for, but perhaps the underlying problem was different.

Comment: @Xtigyro this answer was accurate aside from that small detail. The way to control the order of operations is to create interpolation references between the resources, or in the case of modules between the module's input variables and output values.